# Update fails because directories are locked by php-cgi.exe

Tags: 7, iis, updating

I have some problem when using the Update manager. Some directories get locked by php-cgi.exe, and thus the replacement of the original directories with the newly downloaded ones (which are fresher) is not successful.
It's not a permission issue, since modules can be installed via *Install from a URL* on /admin/modules/install, and that works without problems.

Let's take an example:

1. **Available updates** page (`/admin/reports/updates/update`):

   [image: Available updates]

   Now I check *Select (or other)* module to be updated (**it doesn't matter which module I choose**, the results are the same!! so it's just an example).
2. I hit **"Download these updates"** button.
3. OK, the module's updated instance gets downloaded without a problem:
   "**Updates downloaded successfully**":
   [image: Updates downloaded successfully]
4. Now I click on **Continue**.
5. Here comes the error. The result:
   *"**Update failed!** See the log below for more information.*
   *select_or_other*

   - *Error installing / updating*
   - *File Transfer failed, reason: Cannot copy `D:/Projects/web/drupal-7/tmp/update-extraction-6d8993ac/select_or_other/LICENSE.txt` to `/Projects/web/drupal-7/htdocs/sites/all/modules/select_or_other/LICENSE.txt`.*"
     [image: Update failed!]
6. OK, I'm starting to try to inspect the possible reasons.

   - Here's what my Drupal directory structure looks like: [image: TC directory structure]. I set `../tmp` to be the temporary directory (in `/admin/config/media/file-system`), the Drupal files are in `htdocs`. This is correct, as I can install modules via the GUI, as I mentioned above.
   - When I try to enter the `htdocs/sites/all/modules/select_or_other` directory, I can't, because I get an *"Access denied on file `......sites/all/modules/select_or_other`!"* when opening in Total Commander, and *"`...sites/all/modules/select_or_other` is not accessible. Access is denied"* when opening in Windows Explorer:
     [image: trying to open directory in Total Commander], [image: trying to open directory in Windows Explorer]
   - OK, I right click the folder, and open [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) via its assistant in the context menu. It says this directory is locked by `php-cgi.exe`:
     [image: Unlocker - directory locked by php-cgi.exe]
     I click on "Unlock All", and the folder can now get deleted of itself (as it's not locked anymore by `php-cgi.exe`), so it simply
   - I can find the updated select_or_other module's directory in `tmp`:
     [image: updated module's directory in tmp]
   - so I have to manually move it to `sites/all/modules` directory.

**What can be the possible reasons of the lockup of the directory by `php-cgi.exe`?** (Maybe Windows Cache Extension 1.1 for PHP 5.3 installed via Web Platform Installer? But if yes, why is that for example the deletion of images or similar via the GUI works correctly?)
**What can I do to avoid this problem, and let "Update manager" work?**

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same behaviour with Drupal 7.15 on IIS7/2008R2. It would be great to fix this.

Comment: @Nic: I agree! :)

Comment: I've seen this intermittently. Out of curiosity does refreshing your app pool unlock as well?

Comment: I know it's off topic, but I have to say it - run away from Drupal on IIS. As I can see on the screenshots, you might be using it for local development. Check out [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/) or [Acquia Dev Desktop](https://www.acquia.com/products-services/dev-desktop). If you simply have to use it on a production server, ignore my comment :) I have to use IIS for certain sites and so far it hasn't been a good experience.

Comment: @Brent: I don't know. After running a page in Drupal, the files and directories seem to get locked for an unknown period. By the way, I'm using [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) too, and when I want to update a module using `drush up -y`, I experience the same problem: I have to unlock these files and directories with [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to make it work, otherwise I get the error message that these directories cannot be written/removed, and the update process gets interrupted. If I use Unlocker BEFORE running this process, the update is successful.

Comment: @Ivanhoe123: I disagree. I'm using IIS because I experienced that it's faster than Apache **on Windows**. I don't really understand why people force Apache on every platforms. Under UNIX/Linux, OK. On Windows, it's not - I think IIS is very well optimized, its GUI makes it very easy to setup (I have a lot of experience with configuring Apache, and I'm happy that now, in IIS, I don't have to mess with text files every time I want to change a little setting. I just type `Win+R`, `inetmgr`, click some, and I'm ready),and WPI is good too.Why do you think it's not recommended? I'm really surprised.

Comment: I didn't have such experiences; I used IIS for local dev and then switched to WAMP at the end. The performance is much better on WAMP, at least for me. Also, it is better to try to develop the application on the same type of server as on the production. But if it's working better for you, I guess there's no reason to switch.

Comment: @Ivanhoe123: _"it is better to try to develop the application on the same type of server as on the production"_ - yes, that's a good point! But sometimes I also would like to develop ASP.NET projects, and I don't want to have two different servers on different ports, because it's unnecessary for me - at least, for now. :) Apart from the fact that I have problems with this locking stuff, and currently with searching accented characters on my local server + Drupal, for which I get an exception (I have to change some settings, but I don't know which), I'm using IIS with satisfaction. :)

Comment: @Sk8erPeter - Have you tried restarting the IIS Service? Shot in the dark but they may release the lock. // On 'developing on different systems', you may want to develop on a VM if you're end host is Linux. That also helps keep a clean host system. Check http://vagrantup.com

Comment: @Richard: restarting the web server with one or more running application(s) is of course not a solution. Imagine a live environment... And BTW restarting it all the time is really uncomfortable, there should be an alternative solution. AND suggesting Linux when any Windows-related problem occurs is not a solution either... I like IIS, but the problem mentioned in the question is a bit frustrating.

Comment: Not trying to steer you towards any technology. My apologies if interpreted as such. Can you put that site in an ***App Pool*** and recycle only that Pool? http://stackoverflow.com/a/590629

Answer (score 1):

The reason for php-cgi for having the Lock is because of the "peculiar" way windows handles file access, and php/iis handles "caching". 
Basically you just created the directory and tried to access it, but the handle that created it was not released (so it was still locked). 
This is not a drupal issue, its an IIS/PHP issue
And there is no known workaround that I could find.

Basicly, do the base advise of not using IIS is the best, I have seen this problem in more than just drupal with IIS that I solved by moving to apache HTTPD (on win32).
Mind you that was for back at school, with a project where I was required to use windows 2000.

the best way I know of running drupal on windows is through apache (because of the internal handling of php).

Answer (score 1):

this is not secure that allow to write file from Drupal user interface for updating modules, instead of this use ftp.

but if you want then go to plesk panel of hosting explore httpdocs directory right click and then on permission, now in permission give write permission to Application pool user,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to dig in the right direction:

If you have the same problem from Drush, then I am not sure if this is an IIS problem. Is Drush not just executing PHP from the command line without IIS? You can try this by stopping IIS (iisreset /stop) and then running the Drush update command and I would expect you to get the same result.

The other thing (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to directly comment on Lawri's answer):

> "Basically you just created the directory and tried to access it, but the handle that created it was not released"

Is this really true? From the the original post it looks like he created the folder in "tmp", but the lock is on the already existing folder in "httpdocs".

My guess is that php-cgi tries to copy from tmp to httpdocs, fails for a reason and doesn't remove the lock. So when you investigate after the failure, you see a lock on httpdocs, but I think the initial reason for failing is not a lock, it might be a permission issue on the tmp folder after all!

Comment: if that was the case he could also not move it 'by hand', the directory gets created as part of the upgrade process. IIS is involved through its CGI interface, that is known for causing weird errors. and the error reported is not the "can not access" but "can not copy to" error.